# How can I create a framewrok from a native iOS library?

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie, swift-framework

I'm trying to create a framework from [Lottie iOS](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios) to implement with Xamarin.iOS

According to various searches I conducted, it is necessary to generate a `.xcframework` folder for use in the Xamarin project through **Objective Sharpie**, but it hasn't worked. Another option is to generate two `.archive` files and combine them to create a `.framework` file that I would import into the Xamarin project, but that also did not work.

I have also read that it is necessary to expose classes and methods through a **header** file, but this is an option that I have not fully understood.

Comment: https://github.com/quicoli/LottieSharp